# exit from recursive void method in c++

Tags: c++

I have a recursive void method which is written in c++. How can I exit from this recursive method when I get my needed value.

```
  #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    int a[25];
    char x[25];
    int n, m ;
    string s;
    void go(int pos)
    {
        if(pos == n - 1)
        {
            int suma = a[0];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n - 1;i++)
            {
                if(x[i] == '+')suma += a[i + 1];
                else suma -= a[i + 1];
            }



//here I need hint how to close this method when suma will equal to m
 //if(suma == x) here I should break this method
        return ;


    }
    x[pos] = '+';
    go(pos+1);
    x[pos] = '-';
    go(pos+1);


}

main()
{

    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    go(0);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n- 1;i++)
        cout << x[i]<<" ";



}
```

I need to hint how to break void method when my summa will equal to x data everything was declared please do you know some hint for closing this method and I should get value of x arrays.

Comment: if (X == suma) return;

Comment: Did `if(X == suma)` not work for you?

Comment: Benjamin it goes again for recursive

Comment: It seems to me like you could just make `go` a `bool` function, and use that to know whether or not the continue after a recursive call.

Comment: What is the value that you want to exit on?

Comment: Yes Galik this is recursive method it will call back again and again till 2 power of some n

Comment: What are `n` and `x`? Globals?

Comment: if(X == suma) I want to break this method

Comment: Ron it was declared. N was declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw where you have found your result, and catch at the initial call site

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int a[25];
char x[25];
int n, m ;
std::string s;

struct result_found{};

void go(int pos)
{
    if(pos == n - 1)
    {
        int suma = a[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if(x[i] == '+')suma += a[i + 1];
            else suma -= a[i + 1];
        }
        if (suma == m)
            throw result_found{};
    }
    x[pos] = '+';
    go(pos+1);
    x[pos] = '-';
    go(pos+1);
}

main()
{
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
        std::cin >> a[i];
    try {
        go(0);
    }
    catch (result_found&) {}
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n- 1;i++)
        std::cout << x[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use an 'static bool' flag on the method.
static fields on functions keep their value between several functions calls.

```
void go(int pos)
{
    static bool found=false;
    if (found) return;

    //rest of your code here...
    //of course when you found what are you searching, do found = true;

}
```

Comment: I think global declared of bool also helps in this situation good advice thanks

Comment: @Jakhongir Sabirov Is better use locals for not polluting global namespace. Of course you're writing competitive programming code so you don't care :)

Comment: Using `static` here means the bool isn't allocated on the heap, which you shouldn't do unless you plan on using it until your program is finished. It means you have to manage the memory manually. Using an internal exit condition would be better.

Comment: very odd way to break out of a recursive function, what happens when you call the function for a second time? Much easier to just return a `bool` from the function

Comment: @AlanBirtles you're rigth! I just thinked in the shortest answer to get an AC

Comment: @L.Kue can you give some reference about what you said?